# "ing"-form after "while" / "during" question

Tags: present-tense, present-participles, participle-clauses

I was wondering - when using "while" usually the "ing" form of a verb follows but what if the sentence continues?

Example:

1. While his friends are enjoying (1. ing) their vacation at the beach he finally gets his snow.
2. While his friends are enjoying (1. ing) their vacation at the beach he is finally getting (2. ing) his snow.

(I know it's a bit of "slang" and colloquial but the guy im describing was actually waiting for the snow to fall because it didnt happen until the end of January)

Or even more simple:

1. While his friends are sleeping he watches TV
2. While his friends are sleeping he's watching TV

Thanks for the help!

Comment: They are all **fine**. What slang? I would use a comma: While x is doing y, he watches TV.

Answer (score 0):

The present progressive is mostly used for ongoing actions. The action takes place for a limited time and includes the time of speaking. *While his friends are sleeping, he's watching TV.* -> You are describing two ongoing actions which happen at the same time.

You can use the present simple for storytelling to describe events that happen one after another. The present progressive is then used to describe background events. "He gets home late, so he enters the living room quietly. He sits down on the couch and turns on the telly. *While his friends are sleeping, he watches TV.* Finally he falls asleep on the couch."